# How do I sign a java applet if I bought an SSl through Hostgator

Tags: java, ssl, jar

How can I sign my java applet to use on the web? I purchased SSL through hostgator, but I believe they acquire their certificates through Comodo.

1.) What files do I need to be able to sign the applet, and where would I be able to obtain the files?

2.) Do I have to pay to be provided the files from step 1 above?

3.) Will I still need to sign the applet if the entire site will use https?

I know I have to use keytool to sign the jar, but I am not clear on the questions above?

Thanks for any clarification, as I am very confused as to what I am supposed to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a code signing certificate. As you use a term "purchased SSL", it looks like you didn't read about what certificates are (hint: they are not "SSL") and didn't check what you actually need.

No, you can't use a certificate, issued for SSL/TLS, in code-signing. You need to purchase a certificate for code signing.

Comment: You are correct Eugene, it took me a while to figure this out, but I eventually found the answer I was looking for after much research; however, I will accept this answer as you were kind enough to reply. Thank you!